# Library for Additional touch events

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit, dom-events

While on an iOS device, we get events like `touchstart`, `touchmove`,... end, `gesturestart`, ...move and ..end out of the box..
I wanted to know which free library can be used to get/listen to additional events e.g. Swipe, scrolling related, etc

I know Sencha touch is the best..But before you say that, I wanted to tell that I am looking for a free library..

Also, can we get to know the code for the default implementation.. e.g. When we do the 1-finger slide, the page scrolls automatically.. But there must be some code to do that.. Can we know the code which does that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick googling found these:

- http://www.queness.com/post/6706/9-mobile-framework-to-kick-start-your-mobile-development-career
- http://woorkup.com/2010/08/25/10-useful-frameworks-to-develop-html-based-webapps-for-touch-devices/

*(and even faster skimming led me to believe that the second one is better)*

However it should be noted thatall those 'touch' events are actually other events in disguise: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html